# Como puedo hacer el mismo trabajo del siguiente método pero con Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una lista de HashTables a la que necesito hacerle consultas pero quiero hacerlo con Linq en lugar de tener que usar for o foreach.

```
List<Hashtable> resultado = await sqlselect.SelectFromDatabase(sql,"select * from MobileAplicacion");

            for (int i = 0; i < resultado.Count; i++)
            {
                if (resultado[i]["IdAplicacion"].ToString()=="3002")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(resultado[i]["Descripcion"].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví:

```
 var tes=resultado.Where(x=>x["IdAplicacion"].ToString()=="3002").FirstOrDefault();


            MessageBox.Show(tes["Descripcion"].ToString());
```

Comment: creo que no es necesario usar ToList()